# Durations of chained conditions

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Two related questions here; here, I use Fatigued and Exhausted for illustration, but I'm really asking about the general case of condition "chains" like this.

Question 1: A character is currently under the effect of Fatigued for X rounds, and suffers an effect that would normally apply Fatigued for Y rounds.  Do they end up with (the larger of X and Y) rounds of Exhausted or X+Y rounds?

Question 2: A character is currently under the effect of Exhausted for X rounds, and suffers an effect that would normally apply Fatigued for Y rounds.  Do they end up with X rounds of Exhausted, (the larger of X and Y) rounds, or X+Y rounds?

Comment: Related: [Question on Stacked conditions](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/16151/9625)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple:

> If more than one condition affects a character, apply them all. If effects can't combine, apply the most severe effect. [Source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions)

So you simply pick the longer duration on the worst condition and go from there!

But we *could* get a little more involved in our explanation.

### There's more!

Fatigue and Exhaustion don't normally have durations measured in rounds.

> A fatigued character can neither run nor charge and takes a –2 penalty to Strength and Dexterity. Doing anything that would normally cause fatigue causes the fatigued character to become exhausted. After 8 hours of complete rest, fatigued characters are no longer fatigued.
>
> ...After 1 hour of complete rest, an exhausted character becomes fatigued...
> [Source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions)

So when a fatigued character becomes exhausted, it simply adds an hour to the time they must take to recover.

The only counter I can see to this is the Barbarian's rage, because it gives the resulting fatigue a duration (equal to 2 times the number of rounds spent in the rage). If you were to fatigue a Barbarian while they were raging, the fatigue resulting from the end of Rage would stack with the existing condition and the barbarian would become exhausted and, because of that initial rule above, I would rule it as normal exhaustion with no duration (the *most severe* of the two conditions. Fatigue with a duration, and exhaustion without). The Barbarian would have to rest, as normal, to remove the exhaustion.

It's also worth mentioning that:

> A barbarian cannot enter a new rage while fatigued or exhausted [Source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian#TOC-Rage-Ex-)

So a Barbarian could never exhaust themselves by raging.

### One more thing!

The only other stacking (or "chaining") conditions I can think of are [Fear effects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Fear), and these do have durations.

But the solution remains the same. You pick the worse of the two conditions. (Say, shaken 1 round or frightened 3 rounds, you choose frightened 3 rounds, but it has actually upgraded to panic.) A creature can only be *frightened* from one source. If frightened again, it becomes panicked and attempts to flee from *all sources of danger* instead of only the initial source of fear.

Let's break it down:

- Player A is shaken for 1 round (shaken as a condition usually only lasts 1 round)
- Enemy B casts [Cause Fear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cause-fear), succeeding and affecting Player A with Frightened for 3 rounds
- Player A is now panicked for 3 rounds

Why?

Player A's condition was upgraded from shaken to panicked by the rules for fear effects. It has a duration of 3 rounds because 3 is the most severe of 1 or 3.

Let's look at one more example:

- Player A is panicked for 2 rounds
- Monster B again casts Cause Fear, succeeding and frightening Player A for 4 rounds
- Player A is now panicked for 4 rounds

Why?

Player A was already panicked, and panicked is already the worst fear condition. So out of Paniced (2 rounds) and Frightened (4 rounds) you take the worst conditions and put them together, hence Panicked (4 rounds)

---

***All other (non-"chaining") conditions stack on a character, as per that initial rule once more. So they would all be tracked as separate conditions with their own separate durations.***

Comment: Since it's still a little unclear to me from your example: in a situation where you receive an effect that normally makes you shaken for 2 rounds, and then you receive an effect that makes you shaken for 4 rounds, would that leave you frightened for 2 rounds and then shaken for 2 rounds following that (to finish out the duration of the latter after the former expires), frightened for a full 4 rounds, or frightened for only 2 rounds and then no further condition?  And if you received the effects in the opposite order, would that affect the result?

Comment: @Idran I hope that edit helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

The condition durations do not stack, you track them separately.

As [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions) tells us,

> If more than one condition affects a character, apply them all. If effects can't combine, apply the most severe effect.

Some effects explicitly stack, like [frightened](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Frightened) and [fatigued](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Fatigued), if they are from different sources.

In your example, whenever *fatigued* effects from different sources overlap, the *exhausted* condition [is applied instead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Fatigued).

Therefore,

**Answer 1**: they end up *exhausted* for (the lesser of X and Y) rounds, after that one of the effects passes and they are *fatigued* for the rest of the duration.

**Answer 2**: they end up with X rounds of *exhausted*, after that the *exhausted* effect passes and for the rest of the duration of the *fatigue* effect, if any, they are *fatigued*.

Comment: Fatigue and exhaustion usually last *until rested*

Comment: @Jason_c_o usually yes. But _touch of fatigue_ and _ray of exhaustion_ exist, and there may be other fatigue effects with duration measured in rounds.

Comment: Very true! Somehow I had forgotten about those obvious examples. It's worth mentioning that those durations are measured in minutes, multiples of 10 rounds.